# Javascript loop to get and display every second string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I feel like I had this one in the bag.

Basically, I will create a bill for a client, and I want to set how many installments they can make in order to pay off a service; however, I would like each payment to be bi-monthly, not monthly, e.g:

January, March, May, ...
vs
January, February, March ...

I have entered a value (for when the bill is created) of 2014-01-2014, and temporarily set the installment amount to 12 months, in order to test my work.

The hiddenDate element value will be dynamic, along with the var called maxMonths.

As of now, everything looks great, but not for the months that go past "12"... Can't figure out how to reset a loop value to get this working.

Thanks!

**http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/oe52vz3h/2/**

JavaScript:

```
hiddenDate = document.getElementById("hiddenDate").value;
curDate = hiddenDate.split("-");
curMonth = parseInt(curDate[1]);
curDay = parseInt(curDate[2]);
curYear = parseInt(curDate[0]);

maxMonths = 12; // this will be a dynamic amount, set 12 for testing purposes.
months = ["janvier", "f&eacute;vrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "ao&ucirc;t",     "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "d&eacute;cembre"]
str = "";

moneyTotal = document.getElementById("hiddenTotal").value;
installement = parseFloat(moneyTotal / maxMonths).toFixed(2);

for (var i = curMonth; i < curMonth + maxMonths; i++) {

for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {

    if (i < months.length) {
        increment = i + j - curMonth;
    } else {
        increment = (i + j - curMonth) - months.length;
    }

}

console.log(increment + " " + months[increment]);
month = months[increment];
str += "<li><span>$" + installement + "</span><span>postdat&eacute; &#8594;</span><span>" +     curDay + " " + month + " " + curYear + "</span></li>";
}
document.getElementById("hiddenTerms").innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
month = months[increment];
```

to be

```
month = months[increment % 12];
```

Comment: Fantastic, this allows me to remove the if/else at the same time. I tried using the modulo in the wrong place for hours and probably never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to add 2 to the current month, and wrap around if necessary?

This looks like a problem that can be simplified with the modulus operator.

```
 curMonth = (curMonth + 2) % 12;
```